# Filter on bootstrap collapsion panels

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, filtering

I have a page with a list of Bootstrap collapsion panels. I create these panels dynamically by first querying the database for content, see the code below:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

<?php

        $all_emails = "SELECT * FROM sent_emails";

        if($result = mysqli_query($link, $all_emails)) {
            while($rows = $result->fetch_object()) {
                $db = $rows->timestamp;
                $timestamp = strtotime($db);

                echo '
                    <div class="panel panel-default m'.date("m", $timestamp).'">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse'.$rows->ai.'">
                                    #'.$rows->ai.' | Sent to: '.$rows->mail_to.' | Subject: '.$rows->mail_subject.' <span class="pull-right">| '.$rows->timestamp.' </span>
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse'.$rows->ai.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                '.$rows->mail_message.'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                ';

            }

            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }

?>

</div>
```

This works fine and all, but what I want to accomplish next is adding a filter that only show the panels with a certain class in it. As you can see in the code above I create divs with the classes "panel panel-default m('month') which all have a parent div called "panel-group".

WHen I choose a month from the dropdown button as shown below, I take the value/id of the month into jQuery as input for the filter.

```
<div class="dropdown1">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
         Select month
         <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="select1">
        <li value="january" id="m1" role="presentation"><a href="#">January</a></li>
        <li value="february" id="m2" role="presentation"><a href="#">February</a></li>
        <li value="march" id="m3" role="presentation"><a href="#">March</a></li>
        <li value="april" id="m4" role="presentation"><a href="#">April</a></li>
        <li value="may" id="m5" role="presentation"><a href="#">May</a></li>
        <li value="june" id="m6" role="presentation"><a href="#">June</a></li>
        <li value="july" id="m7" role="presentation"><a href="#">July</a></li>
        <li value="august" id="m8" role="presentation"><a href="#">August</a></li>
        <li value="september" id="m9" role="presentation"><a href="#">September</a></li>
        <li value="october" id="m10" role="presentation"><a href="#">October</a></li>
        <li value="november" id="m11" role="presentation"><a href="#">November</a></li>
        <li value="december" id="m12" role="presentation"><a href="#">December</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--/.dropdown1 -->
```

So far I have the following jQuery code. Every child div of "panel-group" that doesn't have the class let's say m10 (=October) must be hidden.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#select1").on('click', 'li', function(){
        $("#dropdownMenu1").text($(this).text());
        $("#dropdownMenu1").val($(this).text());    

        $(".panel-group").show();

        $(".panel-group .panel.panel-default :not(."+this.id+")").hide();

    });
});
```

I have been trying a lot and have searched all over the internet for an answer that satisfies what I need, but no luck so far :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide all, then show the correct one:

```
$(function(){
    $("#select1").on('click', 'li', function(){
        $("#dropdownMenu1").text($(this).text());
        $("#dropdownMenu1").val($(this).text());    

        $(".panel-group .panel").hide();

        $(".panel-group .panel.panel-default."+this.id).show();

    });
});
```

Comment: I think you meant .show() with the last statement? This doesn't do the trick unfortunately. Weird, because this should work right?

Comment: @MarijnvanGool Also had another typo (.panel1 insead of .panel). Try that - it should work just fine

Comment: $(".panel-group .panel.panel-default").hide();
   
$(".panel-group .panel.panel-default."+this.id).show(); <-- this did the trick however!

Comment: Oh yes, another typo, sorry. Edited. Glad its working for you